# Multiple Ngview for different template-page

Tags: angularjs

I am working angularjs with MVC , where I need two different ng-view based upon condition.

Currently I have put `ng-view` on Account folder view for all pages before login.

But Now I have to show different view (not template) after login where i have menu and other html .

How can i have multiple `ng-view` directive for different base page before and after login page

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can have multiple `ng-view`. If you can change your router, try [`ui-router`](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router). They have something called [*multiple named views*](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views)

Comment: if multiple ng-view is not possible then how do I manage different html for before login and after login... its very common issue where on login html is different I mean no menu and after login html is different with menu items and other stuff

Comment: You can check if the user has logged in or not and depending on that, you can redirect him to different `views` or `states` with a single `ng-view` or `ui-view`. That is possible by both `ngRouter` and `uiRouter`.

Comment: Ok I'll check that option , do u have good article to implement these changes, though I'll search for these. I am just asking if you have better site/blog for this implemetation

Comment: You can get a basic idea from https://thinkster.io/angularjs-jwt-auth. All you need to do is to check for the `token` using `$stateChangeStart` or `$routeChangeStart` for every time the `state/view` changes and then decide to what `state` or `view` you wanna redirect him to.